# SOAP webservice connection getting: no access allow to this class

Tags: soap-api, security, webservices, java

I'm pretty new to salesforce and SOAP but here goes. I've made a connection to my site and then passed in the config to my webservice's object. This goes fine. But then I get this error:

com.sforce.ws.SoapFaultException: my_web_service: no access allowed to this class

Can anyone recommend where I can figure out what settings I need to change to allow this to go through? Like is it a setting in the webservice I'm accessing or is it a setting on the user making the call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the profile of the user you're running the SOAP call as. On the profile view screen near the bottom is a list of "Enabled Apex Class Access" - make sure your class is in this list.

You only need to make the entry point available, e.g. if your web service class makes method calls to another class only the webserivce class would need to be added here.

Comment: This was it! Thanks, eh! I can't tell you how long I've been working on this ^_^

Answer (score 5):

In Salesforce go to Setup, Develop, Apex Classes, Find your class in the list of classes and click on the Security link to the left of the class name. That will display a list of Profiles that have access to the class. If the Profile for the User Name does not appear in the "Enabled Profiles" box, find it on the Left Side and click the right arrow to add it, then save.